# Работа со словами в строке

Tags: java, массивы, строки, arraylist

Не могу понять как решить данное задание:
Надо поменять буквы в предложении: первые буквы сделать последними и в конце ещё добавить:"ay", пока получается только найти пробелы.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       String[] items = sc.nextLine().split("");
       ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));             System.out.println(arr);
       for(int i=0;i<=arr.size()-1;i++){
           if(arr.get(i).equals(" "))
           System.out.print(arr.indexOf(arr.get(i)));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: уточните задачу: буквы в предложении или в словах?

Comment: Буквы в словах предложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод меняет первую и последнюю буквы в словах предложения, которое получает в качестве аргумента и добавляет в конце "ау".

```
 static String changeLetters(String str) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    for (String s : words) {
        builder.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
        builder.append(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
        builder.append(s.charAt(0));
        builder.append("ay");
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}


String s = changeLetters("Abcxyz 123987 Golova"); //s = zbcxyAay 723981ay aolovGay
```

Comment: В конце каждого слова ау и слова не просто реверсировать, а именно первую букву сделать последней в каждом слове.

Comment: @ЭмильМаннапов я поправил ответ, если я вас правильно понял то можно так

Comment: Да, спасибо, пойду изучать StringBuilder)

Comment: Получается вы создали метод, который меняет слова.